# Insert records into records into table from 2 difference source in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just wondering will it be possible to insert records into a table from 2 difference sources in SQL?

Example:

Table 1

```
Number
1
2
```

Table 2

```
Name
Alex
Amy
```

I want to insert records into table 3 from table 1 and table 2 and the result for table 3 should be:

```
Number  Name
1       Alex
2       Alex
1       Amy
2       Amy
```

Any way that I can do it in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a `CROSS JOIN` and a `SELECT ... INTO`:

This join relates every-with-every row. The result will be filled into a new table *on the fly*:

```
SELECT Nrs.Nr
      ,Nms.Name
INTO dbo.TheNewTable
FROM dbo.NumberTable AS Nrs
CROSS JOIN dbo.NameTable AS Nms;
```

See the result:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TheNewTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

- connect for two connections .
- use a script not only in SQL :javca for example.
- use hashmap and hashet ...
- isnert in temporary table(drop on commit for example).
- copy in table 3.
  -don't forget to close connections.